# Best way to handle EC2 instance forced termination

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

I have an EC2 instance which hosts a windows service, .net API and a simple .net website. There's also the added complication of a Route 53 endpoint pointing to it and an https cert being allocated via Amazon certificate manager. Yes, it's a lot of apps on a single instance and I will look at separating them later. I got a message from AWS saying that due to the underlying infrastructure becoming unstable, they'll need to terminate the instance in a week.

Lot of options come to mind, none of which I've tried before or know much about. These options include spinning up another instance, backing up and restoring this instance on to the new one. OR using AWS elastic beanstalk or something to automate the infrastructure setup and code deployment. Which of these (or another) options is most feasible and quick to get working and where should I start looking?

Comment: "they'll need to terminate the instance in a week." are you sure it's termiante and not 'retire'?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If it's just the instance, I'd go for an EBS snapshot and then restore the ec2 instance from it. Finally, swap the IP in Route 53.

It's a relatively quick and rather straight-forward process, that's well documented by AWS and there are loads of how-to's on the Web too.

Here's where to start:

[Create Amazon EBS Snapshot](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/WindowsGuide/ebs-creating-snapshot.html)

and here's [how to restore it](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/prescriptive-guidance/latest/backup-recovery/restore.html).

On the other hand, you could go for a .Net app on Elastic Beanstalk but that requires a bit more work to set up the environment and prepare the app for deployment.

More on [how to create and deploy .NET on Elastic Beanstalk](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/create_deploy_NET.html).